# Netbeans enforcing index file location

Tags: php, ftp, netbeans-8

I'm trying to configure Netbeans 8 to upload and test a simple php project. Here is the relevant setup.

Required project url:

```
http://services.mydomain.com/index.php
```

In the Project Properties-> Run Configuration 
Project url: http://services.mydomain.com 
Index File: index.php

Location of index.php via FTP:

```
ftp://services.mydomain.com/public_html/services/
```

As you can see I'm starting the FTP upload from a different place in the directory structure.

On the server
FTP directory: ~/       (This is the initial directory for FTP)
Web directory: ~/public_html/services/

In my project I have the folder structure:
Source Files
-> config
-> public_html
--> services
----> index.php

I want to keep this setup so I can have some configuration setting outside the web directory in ~/config. Also I don't have admin on server so can't change the initial directories anyway.

The problem is Netbeans is doing validation on the Index File location it wants to see the public_html/services/ in the Index File field (because this is where it is in the project) This gives the URL:

```
http://services.mydomain.com/public_html/services/index.php
```

Which is wrong.

The error I am getting is "Index File must be a valid URL".

Does anyone know of a way to turn this validation off so I can manually set my own URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I am using NetBeans 8.2, but this should work on earlier versions. Also, you can look at the following blog for [Path Mapping](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/path-mapping-in-php-debugger), but I didn't need that.

To solve this:

1. Open the **Project Properties** dialog.
2. Select the **Sources** page.
3. In the **Web Root** directory path, click *Browse...*
4. Navigate to the directory that is your website root and click **Select Folder**. In my case it was the  "public" directory in the Laravel project directory.
5. Click **OK**.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I am using NetBeans 12.6. For my Laravel project I created New Project in NetBeans "PHP Application with Existing Sources".

My index file located in *my-project/public/index.php*

So, I defined in the last step of my project configuration in NetBeans:

Project URL: *http://local.my-project.com/*

Index File: *public/index.php*